# Word Add-in made with Visual Studio 2015 throws exceptions

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I just created a Word Add-in in Visual Studio 2015. I did not make any code changes. When I run it (in Word 2016 x86) and click on the ribbon button, the add-in loads correctly in the task pane but i get the following errors in the console:

> 'iexplore.exe' (Script): Loaded 'Script Code (Windows Internet
>   Explorer)'.  Exception was thrown at line 4243, column 4 in
>   https://localhost:44398/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js 0x800a139e -
>   JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError Exception was thrown at line
>   4261, column 4 in https://localhost:44398/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js
>   0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: SyntaxError Exception was
>   thrown at line 21, column 112492 in
>   https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-win32-16.01.js
>   0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property
>   'attributes' of undefined or null reference

Any ideas why?

Comment: Hello Leonardo, can you share the code snippet throwing this error?

Comment: @JuanBalmori this happens before the Home.js is even loaded... Here is a video of the error happening: https://www.screencast.com/t/5vXjgahe

Comment: interesting, i see a few jquery errors as well. Quick question: is the sample funcitonal? (when you click the buttons the sample works?),  can you please share your Build number as well? thanks!

Comment: Yes... It is not great code... You need to select some text before clicking the button or you get an error (handled and shown in the UI)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a quick sync with the VS team I believe you see those exceptions printed to debug output because we attach the debugger to the internet explorer process that’s hosting the Add-in, which will print out javascript exceptions. They look like they are coming from the jquery and office js libraries, which is why they show up before it even gets to the template code. I think the app should still work correctly you should be able to safely ignore them.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. I have the feeling that this issue might have repercussions on other parts of the API... I could not get getHtml and get Ooxml to work... I'll check again on Monday and I'll let you know for sure.

Comment: Is there a way to report this as a bug?

Comment: yes if you can provide solid repro steps and impact on using the APIs. right now if you ignore those its ok, i would be interested to learn more details about exactly what is failing. thanks

Comment: The biggest issue is that I wasted a lot of my time, finding out whether I was doing something wrong or not... I am sure it can fool other devs into thinking their code is causing this. Also I am not sure whether there is a performance impact, since I cannot compare with an error free equivalent. Ideally, creating an addin from VS and running (without modifying anything) should not throw exceptions. It is a fair expectation.